# Optimized drawing on QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, drawing

I have a little question about how to implement some sort of graphics editor.
For drawing I use this method:
first I check if left mouse button is clicked, then I draw one pixel at event->pos() on my QPixmap, and after that I call update(); to redraw it. I also paint lines on QPixmap between two dots if the mouse is moved with pressed button(because without it it will just some dots). It works pretty well, but I want to know if there's more optimized method to do this. Here's some code(I've skipped parts with zooming, joining missing pixels between to pixels etc.)

```
void Editor::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    painter.drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, image.width() * zoom , image.height() * zoom),
                             image);
}

void Editor::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{

    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        setImagePixel(event->pos());
    }

}

void Editor::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        setImagePixel(event->pos(), true);
    }
}

void Editor::setImagePixel(const QPoint &pos)
{

    QPainter painter(&image);
    if(image.rect().contains(i, j))
    {
        painter.begin(&image);
        painter.setPen(primaryColor);
        painter.drawPoint(i, j);
        painter.end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would use QPainterPath and its API to draw hand-made shapes. Look at its methods : `moveTo()` and `lineTo()`, which will let you get rid of the drawing logic (missing pixels, etc). It is also very easy to combine with mouse events.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot, that really helped! ^_^
I'm so glad I don't have to re-invent the wheel. Have a nice day.

Comment: One more question. I tried to use pens with different width. But it looks not very nice, like this -> http://i.imgur.com/lNdKO.png . I guess it's because I draw a lot of paths all the time. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Did you try the `QPainter::setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true)` ? I don't quite understand the _I draw a lot of paths all the time_ but i'm not sure it's related to the rendered result

Comment: Yes, it looks even worse(lines are nice, but there's some dots with different amount of opacity). I draw paths between current event->pos() of MouseMoveEvent and previous event->pos(), which I store in QSize item.

Comment: You don't have to store anything ? on_mousePress_event : current_path.moveTo(e->pos()); on_mouseMove_event : current_path.lineTo(e->pos()); on_mouseRelease_event : handle 0-sized paths, and store current_path or add undoable command, etc.

Comment: Tried it. Yep, it's nice method, thanks, but the problem stays here. i.imgur.com/JR2Rj.png - I've pointed out pixels that "ruin" the line. –

Comment: Hmm, i don't really know what's happening in your app, but i'd suggest to play around with QPen's CapStyle and JoinStyle hints. This is my last suggestion as I can't guess what's going on really. Concerning the anti-aliasing hint; it's normal to see _some dots with different amount of opacity_, it's even the principle of the thing, and it's what we are looking for usually. Maybe your composition mode is not well chosen, dunno...